# Display records per day

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id | date | name
```

And the desired output is displaying the record per day of the month:

```
Day 1 - name1 , name2, name3
Day 2 - name4
Day 3 - name5, name6
.
.
.
```

I know how to do this with php but I wonder If it is possible to do it with a mySQL sentence ..

Anyone can help?

Comment: use group by and group_concat in mysql

Comment: Just do it in PHP! :-)

Comment: Wouldnt be more efficient to do it in SQL? At least It just requires one line of code and looks very neat!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DAYOFMONTH(date) AS Day, GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ', ') AS Name
FROM table1
GROUP BY Day
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecc33/1

Comment: +1 only answer considering the day part of the date :)

Comment: Needs to use GROUP_CONCAT rather than CONCAT_WS

Answer (score 0):

```
Select date,group_concat(name) from table1 group by date
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Using [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)() alows you to do that:

```
SELECT date,group_concat(name)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY date
```

The group in this query will be done by date, not the day of the month. If you have one record in `2013-01-01` it will not be in the same group as `2013-02-01`. If that is what you are looking for, @Aziz's answer is what you are looking for.